# How to open and close modal with same hotkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to open and close modal window with same hotkey:

```
if !$('#new-stuff').length or $('#new-stuff').is(':hidden')
  $(document).keydown( (e) ->
    if e.altKey && e.which == 65
      e.preventDefault
      modal.open(
        content: '<input type="text" placeholder="New stuff here!" id="new-stuff"><br /><input type="submit" value="Do stuff!">'
      )
  ).keyup( ->
    $('#new-stuff').focus()
  )
else
  $(document).keyup( (e) ->
    if e.altKey && e.which == 65
      e.preventDefault()
      modal.close()
  )
```

When I'm pressing `alt + A` modal is opening and focus is on the input. But when I'm pressing `alt + A` again it focuses on input again, but not closing.

```
!$('#new-stuff').length or $('#new-stuff').is(':hidden')
```

Both are `false`, but `$('#new-stuff').focus()` is happening. Why?
And how to close modal with `alt + A`?

**UPDATE**
Here is working code:

```
$(document).keydown( (e) ->
  if e.altKey && e.which == 65
    if $('#new-stuff').is(':visible')
      e.preventDefault()
      modal.close()
    else
      e.preventDefault
      modal.open(
        content: '<input type="text" placeholder="New stuff here!" id="new-stuff"><br /><input type="submit" value="Do stuff!">'
      )
).keyup( ->
  $('#new-stuff').focus() if $('#new-stuff').is(':visible')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to put the conditional inside the event function.  Something like this:

```
$(document).keyup( (e) ->
  if e.altKey && e.which == 65
    if $('#new-stuff:visible)')
      # hide it
    else
      # show it
 )
```